# nginx setup for multiple project including react SPA with browserhistory

Tags: php, reactjs, nginx, routes, browser-history

Currently I have three projects which I want to run on same domain.

root directory /home/theme (html + css + php )

1st directory /home/community (React with browserhistory, so all path should redirect to index.html)

2nd directory /home/api (node express)

domain name wwww.xyz.com

so www.example.com/community/*  should riderct to community directory.

But browserHistory.replace('/login') redirect me to www.example.com/login instead of www.example.com/community/login.

Also the domain www.example.com.anything/else/here/community/ should redirect to http://www.example.com/anything/else/here/community/login using react routing,
http://www.example.com/anything/else/here/ should point to theme directory and http://www.example.com/anything/else/here/api should point to api directory